# Fail to communicate with driver via CreateFile in 64 bits

Tags: driver, scsi

I am a scsi driver developer.

I write a user space program to get data from driver via CreateFile.

It works ok when testing in 32 bit windows environment but in 64 bit the following error appears:

> CreateFile return -1. GetLastError() would return 2. (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)

I have called `IoCreateSymbolicLink` when driver initializes and
it returns success when I am using windbg to see debug output.

Anyone has met this kind of problem?

Comment: When you say `CreateFile` returns -2, what do you mean?  `CreateFile` returns a `HANDLE` value or `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, which is actually -1.  Were you instead referring to what `GetLastError()` returns after the `CreateFile` call?  Also, `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` is 2, not -2.

Comment: sorry, i mean CreateFile returns a HANDLE -1. then i using GetLastError() i got 2 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.

Comment: Are you sure your driver loaded correctly on the 64-bit system?  That might explain why your user-space code couldn't find it.

Comment: yes, i am sure driver loaded correctly. it is a SCSI driver, PCI HBA card simulate as a Harddisk and already install windows 7 drivers

Comment: Can you see the device / symlink using a tool like WinObj (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657)?  This sounds rather odd...

Comment: i can get from WinObj and QuickView (http://www.opferman.com/Software/QuickView/). 

Name              Type              SymLink
JQBTScsi          SymbolicLink      \Device\Scsi\JQT51821

but still can't CreateFile